# SQL queries CPU usage server 99% Microsoft Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a database that located on Azure. I wrote automatic email processes with dynamic data. For dynamic data i am using sql queries for taking a data from db to my server. But all my queries, even small take 99% of cpu usages. I am using node js server with async library. Here is an Example of my MSSQL queries:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
    st.id,
    st.firstName,
    st.lastName,
    st.email,
    st.lastLogin,
    st.phone,
    st.gender,
    sa.title,
    bra.Title AS brand,
    ss.SaleDate,
    teh.sDate,
    sa.imageUrl,
    sa.guid,
    sa.id saleId
FROM dbo.Students st
INNER JOIN KEY_SalesToStudents ss
    ON (st.ID = ss.studentID)
INNER JOIN Sales sa
    ON (sa.ID = ss.SaleID)
INNER JOIN Brands bra
    ON (sa.BrandID = bra.ID)
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblEmailHistory teh
    ON st.id = teh.studentID
WHERE st.id NOT IN (SELECT
    ueb.studentID
FROM dbo.tblEmailBan ueb
WHERE ueb.targetID = 3
OR ueb.targetID = 24)
AND CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, ss.SaleDate)) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
AND st.deleted = 0
AND ISNULL(teh.sDate, '') = ''
OR CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 14, teh.sDate)) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
AND ISNULL(teh.sDate, '') = ''
OR CONVERT(date, teh.sDate) >= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())
ORDER BY ss.SaleDate DESC
```

Comment: Please use parentheses around the last 4 `AND/OR` conditions (i.e. `AND ISNULL(teh.sDate, '') = '' OR CONVERT(...` ) to ensure the correct precedence is given per your business logic. I suspect you want to write it as `AND ( ISNULL(teh.sDate, '') = ''
OR CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 14, teh.sDate)) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) ) 
AND ( ISNULL(teh.sDate, '') = ''
OR CONVERT(date, teh.sDate) >= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()) )`

Comment: When you run that query in SQL Management Studio and tick the "actual execution plan" option with results, does it give you any index advice? Over large datasets you will need to index those date columns to get any decent performance.